# Become / get, successfully / effectually, together / common / united

Tags: grammar, expressions, sentence, translation, names

Currently I'm looking for a product name. The goal of this product is that everyone can get successful with the power of a network (together, united)

But I don't know which combination makes sense:

- Get successfully together?
- Get together successful?
- Become together successful?
- Become successfully together?
- ....?

Thanks for any hint :)

Comment: Succeed together.

Comment: @Tobias: These sites don't like *any* questions. Also, the editors specialize in being "cute." Way too cute! Your sentence: "The goal of this product is that everyone can get successful with the power of a network (together, united)" is better stated as "**...can be successful with the power of Won** [after One, meaning 'united']." Call your product "**Won**" (we've done it [past tense], "we've won!").

Comment: Tobias, I rolled back your edit because the place to ask the sort of additional thing that you edited in is either here in comments, or (better) on our [meta site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, Mauli is somewhat correct in that this site has particular standards that it strives to uphold; your question appears not to meet those standards as it was originally written, so please check out the links included in the "put on hold" block for information about how the site works, the sort of question we are looking to host, and where else you might want to check for answers or ideas first.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above are correct for what you'd like.

"Become/Get successful together" is the way to go.